# How to maintain user specific values to be used in test cases at workspace level in Tosca?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, tosca

My requirement is to maintain user specific values like username, password, time zone etc. at workspace level so that users can set it up in their own workspace.

If I use Test Configuration Parameters, they sync into the central repository and change for everyone.

I can maintain them in buffers but I delete all the buffers at the end of the test case to avoid any wrong buffer pickup in the future.

I think deleting only buffers created in a test case at the end of the test case would solve this but I'll have to create a list of buffers to delete in each test case.

Is there a better approach to satisfy my requirement?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.